# Kotlin-Android First App Unresolved Reference TextView Button etc

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I'm new to Android & Kotlin development.

I wanted to get started with a simple "Hello World", but am already running into problems.

I added a Textview to my MainActivity and want to set an onClick listener to change the text of a TextView I dragged into the activity.

The compiler is now complaining that 'TextView' is an unresolved reference (it does the same with Buttons etc.).

I then added a kotlinx import as suggested by a website, but this fails to solve anything. Code sample below, anything with an asterisk as a line comment was added by me.

```
package com.example.my.mynewapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragmentX.view.* // *

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.testView) as TextView  // *
        textView.setOnClickListener { // *
            textView.text = "You clicked me! You flipping clicked me!" // *
        } // *

    }
}
```

Would anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Just solved it, apparently you have to import android.widget.TextView, which solves the issue. No need to downvote, we all have to learn.

Comment: no need to use findViewById in kotlin. you can directly access your view using id.

Comment: @AkshayRaiyani  can you give an example of how to use id to access the view?

Comment: @user2868623 here is a good blog on how to use id to access the view. https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should have been automatically imported, but there should be

```
import android.widget.<WhateverIsMissing>
```

Replace WhateverIsMissing with the reference that is unresolved

Comment: Yeah, figured that out 1.5 years ago (see my comment on the OP). But thanks for taknig the time to respond.

Answer (score 2):

if you use Android Studio v.4.2.1 you have to add this line in (build.gradle) file like this:-

```
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating `activity_main.xml` in your class.  
Does this `TextView` belong to the above layout?  
If it does then you don't need `findViewById()` 
Just add to your imports:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

and **not**:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragmentX.view.*
```

then use `testView` (this is the id of the `TextView` unless it's a typo) anywhere in your activity class.

Comment: Yes, the TextView named 'testView' belongs to the layout. Adding your import does nothing; I can only compile when I explicitly add 'import android.widgets.TextView'. What do you mean with 'inflating' the xml-file in my class?

Comment: @TheFox if this is the case then there is a problem because you should import all the views of the layout 1 by 1. But **this is not the case with Kotlin**. One advantage of using Kotlin is that **you don't need findViewById()** inside an activity to access its views. You just import the layout like I did and that' it. If after that the TextView is not recognized then **it does not belong** to `activity_main.xml`, or maybe you need to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: for all clarity, I have to import android.widgets.TextView, don't I? Cleaning and rebuilding doesn't solve the issue, activity_main.xml does contain the TextViews however.

Comment: `android.widget.TextView` is **autiimported** in any class that uses in its code a TextView. You don't have to import it. Even if you write something like `val tv: TextView...` AS will import `android.widget.TextView` or you will by pressing Alt Enter and accepting the suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467501/how-do-i-turn-autoimport-on-in-android-studio/57467510#57467510

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new view (in this case `TextView`), the IDE will default its `id` to `textView`. **The IDE will increment the `id` every time you add a new view of the same kind** (`textView2`, `textView3`, and so on) **even when you already deleted the previous views**. For [example](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#DisplayMessage):

```kotlin
// Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
    text = message
}
```

If you get `Unresolved reference: textView` from the `R.id.textView`, check the corresponding XML file. Specifically, the *Component Tree*:

[image: Component Tree]

To change the `id`, select the view and in the *Attributes* window, change the `id`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to check if your imports seem complete:

In case you have defined more than one layout for your activity, fragment, etc. make sure that classes of corresponding controls match across layouts. This is the most common situation where I see this error message.

Answer (score -1):

add **apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'** in the build.gradle
by double shift to search and write "build" then add the plugin in the **dependencies** section then import option should appear for you

Answer (score -2):

- Under the project folder there are gradle scripts
- Open the build.gradle (module:your app name)
- add  'id-android-extensions' into the plugins
- then sync it