# How do I turn AutoImport on in Android Studio?

Tags: kotlin-android-extensions

In [the build your first Android app Kotlin instructions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin/index.html#6) it is shown to use File-> Other Settings -> Default Settings to enable auto-imports.

However this option is missing in Android Studio 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

File->Other Settings->Settings for New Projects -> Other Settings -> Auto Import

Then I checked Add unambiguous imports on the fly.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: Easy to find though. Since bits of the IDE get moved around occasionally no need to post another response that will soon be outdated as well. Just search the settings for "imports".